# Error: function crashed. Details: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Error: function crashed. Details:
Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array. and how can i send notification to all token save in my database if more than one user is login

here is my database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb81p.png)

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//exports.sendNewTripNotification = functions.database.ref('/{uid}/shared_trips/').onWrite(event=>{
    exports.sendNewEmergencyNotification = functions.database.ref('messages/{id}').onCreate(event=>{


    console.log('User to send notification');

    var ref = admin.database().ref(`users/allusers/${pushId}/token`);
    return ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
         const payload = {
              notification: {
                  title: 'An Emergency has been Reported!!',
                  body: 'Tap here to view details..'
              }
         };

         admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.val(), payload)

    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
})
```

Comment: `snapshot.val()` probably doesn't contain the data that you think it contains. Also you are ignoring the promise returned from `sendToDevice`.

Comment: Thank you very much @DougStevenson .  can you please show me the right way to execute this function? Im new in firebase and currently doing my school project.   Thank you very much in advance.